# Laravel migration: pivot table role_user doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Using Laravel 5, I am making a new project with a `n:n` relationship between `User` and `Role`.

When I empty my database and type the command: `php artisan migrate:install` (which works) followed by: `php artisan migrate`, I get the following errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'manon.role_user' doesn't exist
(SQL: alter table `role_user` add `user_id` int not null, add `role_id` int not null)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'manon.role_user' doesn't exist
```

I was inspired by [this](http://alexsears.com/article/adding-roles-to-laravel-users/) tutorial.

Here are some simple bits of code:

In Role.php:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

In User.php:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

roles migration:

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

role_user migration:

```
class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('role_id');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

users migration:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

should be

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

Note the change: `table` has changed to `create` as you are creating this table, not altering it, you cannot alter something which does not exist :)

The migration is also called `CreateRoleUserTable`, so indicates it's a creation not an alteration.